# How to uninstall pre-commit

Tags: python, uninstallation, pre-commit.com

Following the "non administrative installation" instructions on Pre-Commit's [website](http://pre-commit.com/), I ran the following command:

```
curl http://pre-commit.com/install-local.py | python
```

These instructions provide the following note: "*(To upgrade: run again, to uninstall: pass uninstall to python).*"

Right now, I want to uninstall pre-commit. I am trying to understand how to pass uninstall to Python. I'm not sure what passing `uninstall` entails.

I've tried:

```
curl http://pre-commit.com/install-local.py | python --uninstall
curl http://pre-commit.com/install-local.py | --uninstall python
curl http://pre-commit.com/install-local.py | uninstall | python
```

..and a couple other probably even more nonsense variations. All of which result in:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Unknown option: -n
usage: /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
100  2590  100  2590    0     0  14175      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14230
(23) Failed writing body
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are very granular options -> `pre-commit uninstall -h`

To remove every hook:
`pre-commit uninstall -t pre-commit -t pre-merge-commit -t pre-push -t prepare-commit-msg -t commit-msg -t post-commit -t post-checkout -t post-merge -t post-rewrite`

Idiot-proof uninstall:

```bash
pip install pre-commit \
&& pre-commit uninstall -t pre-commit -t pre-merge-commit -t pre-push -t prepare-commit-msg -t commit-msg -t post-commit -t post-checkout -t post-merge -t post-rewrite \
&& pip uninstall pre-commit -y
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
curl http://pre-commit.com/install-local.py | python - uninstall
```

Comment: So that resulted in the following note: `Cleaned ~/.pre-commit-venv ~/bin/pre-commit`.

But pre-commit still seems to be installed. Any reason that you could think of that would keep it from being fully uninstalled with the above command?

Comment: Not sure, I tried on my machine and it seemed to remove it? https://gist.github.com/madebydavid/1e225ef912984044e02996993b5f269e

Comment: @kuanb maybe you also ran `pre-commit install` which you'd want to `pre-commit uninstall` to undo? (or `rm .git/hooks/pre-commit` if you've already purged it as per above)